# Running Windows Powershell script always from task scheduler

Tags: powershell, taskscheduler

This might be a very basic question. I have FileWatcher script in windows powershell which I want to run **always** so that it keeps watching a particular location for files. when I run it from Windows Powershell IDE its run perfectly fine. I understand that I can schedule a task in windows task scheduler for that but what's happening is that the task runs and then comes back in "Ready" status. This is NOT working. I think it should be in "Running" state always. I might be missing something. Please kindly help with your valuable suggestions.

Comment: If it should always run, you should make a service out of it. Not a scheduled task.

Comment: and how do I do that ... for e.g. I want to create a service to run a powershell script.

Comment: I'd suppose that the `FileWatcher.ps1` script uses `Register-ObjectEvent`? Then events, event subscriptions, and the event queue exist **only in the current session**. If you close the current session, the event queue is discarded and the event subscription is canceled. Run the script at user logon startup using **-NoExit** (something like `powershell.exe -NoLogo -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Hidden -NoExit -File 'full\path\to\FileWatcher.ps1'`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with TaskSchedule…

[Running PowerShell scripts as a “service” (Events: Prologue)](https://blog.start-transcript.com/2012/01/22/running-powershell-scripts-as-a-service-events-prologue/)

but this is also what permanent Event Subscriptions are for or setting up as user10675448 suggest, make it a real service.

[How to run a PowerShell script as a Windows service](https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-as-a-windows-service/)

[Windows PowerShell - Writing Windows Services in PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt703436.aspx)

> This article presents the end result of that effort: A novel and easy
>   way to create Windows Services, by writing them in the Windows
>   PowerShell scripting language. No more compilation, just a quick
>   edit/test cycle that can be done on any system, not just the
>   developer’s own.

There is also this approach...

[PowerShell and Events: Permanent WMI Event Subscriptions](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/14/powershell-and-events-permanent-wmi-event-subscriptions)

> Unlike the temporary event, the permanent event is persistent object
>   that will last through a reboot and continue to operate until it has
>   been removed from the WMI repository.
>
> There are multiple ways of setting up the WMI events and I will be
>   covering 3 of those ways (as they deal with PowerShell) in this
>   article.